# URL encoding in javascript

Tags: javascript, url-encoding

I have this parameter `user@ampliflex.co.in` in my url. I want to encode it using javascript, I dont want `.` in my url.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Comment: Can I ask why don't you want `.` in your URL?

Comment: `.` isn't a reserved character in URLs, so it doesn't make sense to URL Encode it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you encode `.` in JavaScript, the browser is allowed to unencode it before sending it to a server.

[*RFC 3986 section 6.2.2.2.  Percent-Encoding Normalization*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.2) says

> The percent-encoding mechanism (Section 2.1) is a frequent source of
> variance among otherwise identical URIs.  In addition to the case
> normalization issue noted above, some URI producers percent-encode
> octets that do not require percent-encoding, resulting in URIs that
> are equivalent to their non-encoded counterparts.  These URIs **should
> be normalized by decoding any percent-encoded octet that corresponds
> to an unreserved character**, as described in Section 2.3.

`'.'` is an unreserved character in URLs.

> unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"